# Designing Azure Cognitive Search Schema for Office Documents and PDFs with User Filtering

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm working on implementing Azure Cognitive Search for indexing and searching office documents (e.g., Word files) and PDFs. The goal is to store the contents of these files in an index and provide filtering capabilities based on the user_id field. I'm seeking advice on the best schema design for this use case.

Option 1: Should I create a single field (e.g., "content") and upload the entire PDF/Word file's text into it?
Option 2: Alternatively, should I create a collection with each row representing the text content of one page of the PDF or one section of the Word file?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, creating a single field (e.g., "content") and uploading the entire PDF/Word file's text into it is a good approach if you want to index the entire document and provide filtering capabilities based on the `user_id` field.

However, if you need to filter search results based on specific pages or sections of the document, or if you need to extract certain types of information from the document, then Option 2 is a better approach.

For more detailed understanding and reference you can check [Azure Cognitive Search Sample Data](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-sample-data#azure-cognitive-search-sample-data)  which showcase implementation on mixed content types, including HTML, JPG, PDF, PowerPoint, Word, PNG, and TXT files and skillset processing of multiple content types using a combination of built-in skills that can help in implementing with your own data and schema design.